# computer keeps crashing with read/writing files

Tags: python, file

I am not sure why my computer keeps crashing when using this program I tried editing it by closing the file each time I run but it still crashes.

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
text = str(text)
looper= text.count(",")
f.close()
god= open("dog.txt","w+")
god.write("Passwords")
god.close()
block=""
for count in range(looper):
    first= (text.find(','))
    second= (text.find(':'))
    block = text[first:second]
    text = text[:first] + text[second:]
    god= open("dog.txt","a")
     god.write(block)
     god.close()
```

I am trying to take items from a text file and format them into a new text file.

EDITED CODE:

```
    f = open("testfile.txt", "r")
    text = f.read()
    text = str(text)
    looper= text.count(",")
    f.close()
    god= open("dog.txt","w+")
    god.write("Testing")
    god.close()
    for count in range(looper):
        block = ""
        first= (text.find(':'))
        second= (text.find(','))
        block= text[first:second]
        text = text[second:]
        text = text[first:]
        print (block)
        god= open("dog.txt","a")
        god.write(block)
        god.close()
```

In the first section of code I didn't have the string block clearing and I didn't have the string text updating so what would happen is that each time it looped block would duplicate it self

```
    EX:
    loop1) :helloworld
    loop2) :helloworld:helloworld
    loop3) :helloworld:helloworld:helloworld
```

making those two changes fixed the problem.

Comment: Your entire computer crashes? With what error? I don't see any suspect code here. Might be a hardware problem.

Comment: Well what happens is that it freezes for like 20 minutes so I restart the computer to get it working again.

Comment: If it is a hardware problem is there anything I can do so it will run more smoothly.

Comment: Can you add a print statement and run it? See what looper is evaluating to.

Comment: @CarlosO'gorman That's not a crash. Have you debugged it? What's the value of `looper`? Have you checked what the last expression to execute is?

Comment: ok adding the print statement helped. There where two problems running with it I will explain by editing the question.

Comment: Please show your expected inputs and outputs... There's probably no good reason to read an entire file into memory twice

Comment: when formatting to a new file I did                                                                                                                   god= open("dog.txt","a")
        god.write(block)
        god.close()